# write ECONNRESET error and socket connection checking in node.js

Tags: javascript, sockets, node.js, error-handling, socket.io

I get this error occasionally when running my node.js script.

```
events.js:66
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: write ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:768:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:592:19)
```

What causes this error? I read someplace that this is caused due to attempting to write data to a closed socket. **Is that right?**

If that is the case, **How do I check if a socket connection is active?** 
I found this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546627/how-to-check-if-socket-still-connected), but no one had answered there.

And thirdly, **is a simple try catch around the socket.write statement, enough to handle this error?** Or does it emit error events which I must handle?

Comment: Checking would be completely pointless. Even if it was fine when you checked, it could still fail when you attempt to write to it.

Comment: Oh.. what about the last question? Would just a try..catch handle it?

Comment: I believe so, but I'm not that familiar with node.js, so I didn't answer.

Comment: I have the same error when my server are trying to write to a closed socket connection. And a try/catch are not able to grab the exception. (I'm using node v0.10.8)

Comment: +1 Having the same problem. Did you solve this in any way?

Comment: I just used a process.on to handle unhandled exceptions.  

    `process.on('uncaughtException', function(e) {
 console.log(e.stack);
});`

Answer (score 0):

we've seen it with http-proxy and the issue was reported here:  https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/331

nodejs would throw if there "error" (and only "error") event is not handled.